# React: How to display a default object and highlight li bold?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components, html-lists

I am fairly new to React and was wondering if anybody could give me an insight on a problem I am stuck with.

Right now I have a parent(Hello.js) component and two children(Mixer.js and renderCont.js) at the same level.

I am trying to render a list in the Mixer.js and display its corresponding objects in the Hello.js through by passing the values into RenderCont.js. I've gotten to a point where nothing is displayed before I click on any of the list to pass on a object.

From here is where I am stuck: I want the first object of the list to be displayed as a default, at the same time bold the first in the list. And then execute the as I have below.

This is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow so I'm not sure if my question makes sense with the attached codes but I will greatly appreciate any kind of support.

Parent Hello.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RenderCont from './renderCont.js';
import Mixer from './Mixer';

class Hello extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        items: [{
            id: 0,
            name: "First",
            background: "white"
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Second",
            background: "yellow"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Third",
            background: "blue"
        }],
        selectedItem: 0
        }
        this.handle = this.handle.bind(this)
    }

    handle(value) {
        // console.log(this.state.selectedItem);
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: value
        })
      }

      render() {
        const list = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            return(item);
        })
        return (
        <div>
            <Mixer item={list} onClick={this.handle} selected={this.state.selectedItem}/>
            <ul id = "todo" > 
                <RenderCont item={this.state.selectedItem}/>
            </ul>
        </div>
      ) 
    }
}

export default Hello;
```

Mixer.js Child1:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Mixer extends Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    }

    handleClick(item){
        this.props.onClick(item);
    }

    renderTodos(propItems) {
          return (
              <div>
                {propItems.map((item) => (
                <li className={this.props.selected === item ? 'media clicked' : 'media'}
                key={item.id} onClick = {() => this.handleClick(item)}> 
                    {item.name}  
                </li>
                ))}
           </div>
          )
      }

      render() {
          return ( 
            <div className="yoyoyo">
                {this.renderTodos(this.props.item)}
            </div>
      ) 
    }
}

export default Mixer;
```

Second Child Comp renderCont.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RenderCont extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderBox(item){
        return(
            <div style={{color:item.background}}>
                {item.id}
                {item.name}
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
    return ( 
        <div className="yoyo">
            {this.renderBox(this.props.item)}
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default RenderCont;
```

and the CSS:

```
.yoyo{
  left: 500px;
  background-color:red;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}

.media{
  color: black;
}
.clicked{
  font-weight: 900;
}

.yoyoyo{
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is some mismatch between the initial and eventual value of `this.props.selected` in `Mixer.js`. You initially set `this.state.selectedItem = 0`, and this is what is initially passed as the `selected` prop to `Mixer`. But the test you apply in that component is

```
this.props.selected === item ?
```

While there is one `item.id` that === 0, there is never an `item` that === 0. So no items are highlighted at first. But then, once an `item` is clicked and `selectedItem` is actually set to an `item`, the entry is made bold.

So it looks like you need to either make your initial selection equal to the `item.id === 0` reference, or consistently refer to `items` within your components by their `id`'s.

Comment: Thanks Andy. How would I implement referring to items within my component's by the id's? Also, the corresponding object should be displayed through the renderCont.js. Do you have any suggestions?